# wso2 xpath expression in property mediator doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, xpath, properties, wso2, mediator

I am trying to populate a property in a WSO2 proxy. I'am using the following syntax and xpath expression:

```
<property expression="//RelationValueList/PersonnelRelationValueUnitType[RelAttrId='R54' and DateTo=max(//RelationValueList/PersonnelRelationValueUnitType[RelAttrId='R54']/DateTo/xs:dateTime(.))][last()]/RelationValue" name="RelValue" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

This Xpath expression is working fine in an online Xpath tester. But when using it in WSO2 expression of a property mediator it gives me the following Eclipse error:

**wso2 unknown synapse configuration tag**

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXciG.jpg)

The XML document looks like this:

```
<GetPersonnelResponse>
 <GetPersonnelResult>
    <RelationValueList>
       <PersonnelRelationValueUnitType>
          <RelAttrId>C1</RelAttrId>
          <RelationValue>1234</RelationValue>
          <DateFrom>1900-01-02T00:00:00</DateFrom>
          <DateTo>2199-12-31T00:00:00</DateTo>
       </PersonnelRelationValueUnitType>
       <PersonnelRelationValueUnitType>
          <RelAttrId>R54</RelAttrId>
          <RelationValue>GEN123</RelationValue>
          <DateFrom>1900-01-02T00:00:00</DateFrom>
          <DateTo>2017-12-04T00:00:00</DateTo>
       </PersonnelRelationValueUnitType>
       <PersonnelRelationValueUnitType>
          <RelAttrId>R54</RelAttrId>
          <RelationValue>GEN456</RelationValue>
          <DateFrom>2017-12-05T00:00:00</DateFrom>
          <DateTo>2099-12-31T00:00:00</DateTo>
       </PersonnelRelationValueUnitType>
    </RelationValueList>
 </GetPersonnelResult>
</GetPersonnelResponse>
```

Xpath 2.0 is enabled in WSO2esb.
I need to select the RelationValue with the highest DateTo value. If there are multiple values, I take the last one.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Is that the complete error log?

Comment: That's the error from Eclipse. I just added  a screenshot of the full error message.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You use namespace xs: in your expression. You need to define it in top parent tag of it mediator.

Comment: I added xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" to the property mediator but still no luck. The same error occurs.When I remove the (.) characters from the xs:dateTime then Eclipse doesn't give me an error when saving. But when running it's also not working.But it seems that the (.) characters are not allowed.